# Pentaho User Console, LDAP, TLS negotiation failure

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, pentaho, openldap

I am trying to connect PUC (Community Edition, version 9.1) with openLDAP (version 2.4.48).

I have eddited the

```
/pentaho-solutions/system/securities.properties
```

and

```
/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-security-ldap.properties
```

files according to the documentation:

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Setup/Administration/User_Security/Implement_Advanced_Security/030

However after trying to log in, I am getting the following error:

> TLS: can't accept: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong
> version number. 5ffd36f1 conn=17404 fd=12 closed (TLS negotiation
> failure)

I have tried importing the ldap certificate in /jre/lib/security/cacerts:

`$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -file $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/ldap.cert.x509 -alias ldap_cert -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

and in /pentaho-server/tomcat/security/pentaho_tomcat.key.jks:

`$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -file $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/ldap.cert.x509 -alias ldap_cert -keystore /global/pentaho-server/tomcat/security/pentaho_tomcat.key.jks`

But unfortunatelly the error remains.
The version of Java is "1.8.0_271".

Could anyone please suggest what other actions are necessary in order to integrate Pentaho User Console with LDAP?

Comment: have you modified repository.xml? can you re-verify applicationContext-security-ldap.properties values. also you can try to use java 1.8.0_251/261